# Problems with code

Tags: c#

```
try
{

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.site.ru/group/" + gr);
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.CookieContainer = cookies;
    request.UserAgent = "Opera/9.80 (Windows 7; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    HttpWebResponse response_headers = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream stream = response_headers.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
    string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    /*if (response_headers.Headers["Location"].Contains("alted"))
    {
        log("[-] GROUP is " + gr + " closed\r\n");
        return -2;
    }*/
    string gash = Regex.Match(response, @"gwtHash:""(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
    string grpId = Regex.Match(response, @"state:""st.cmd=altGroupMain&amp;st.groupId=(?<id>[^""]+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
}
catch { log("[?] Can't parse ash and grpId\r\n"); return -1; }
```

This code works successfully when constraction if {} is commented. But when I delete comment and run it I receive `[?] Can't parse ash and grpId`
Why?=\

Comment: response_headers.Headers["Location"] must be null, so it raise exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**response_headers.Headers["Location"]** must be null, so it raise exception. Insert verification:

```
if (response_headers.Headers["Location"] != null && response_headers.Headers["Location"].Contains("alted"))
    {
        log("[-] GROUP is " + gr + " closed\r\n");
        return -2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that message because you have a catch everything block around all your code:

```
catch { log("[?] Can't parse ash and grpId\r\n"); return -1; }
```

This is a bad practice. Remove the try/catch block and let the original exception show itself. This will make it possible to see what the real problem is.